# Using custom functions inside pd.eval() and pd.query()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
def f(a):
    print(a)
    if a%2==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
temp = pd.DataFrame({'hello':[1,2,3,4]})
```

When I try :

```
pd.eval("temp.hello.apply(f)")
```

**Output**

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

but

```
pd.eval("temp.hello.apply(f)",engine = 'python')
```

works

**Output**

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: hello, dtype: bool
```

I would like to use a custom function to filter my rows. How can I do that while using 'numexpr' for speed?

Comment: Hi, your code works fine and does not raise TypeError.

Comment: @Laurent Yeah , I forgot to close the question. Updating to pandas pandas==1.4.2 made it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Pandas 1.4.2 resolved the issue.